# is_front_page breaks with url parameters generated by a plugin

Tags: plugins, homepage, conditional-content, multi-language

I have a website that displays a specific layout feature only on the homepage, and this is working fine. However, the client has suggested that they would like the website to be bilingual, and so I added a plugin to allow the transition between two languages.

Unfortunately, the plugin adds `/?lang=cy` to the URL and I fear it's causing my layout feature to break.

The conditional is relatively straight forward:

```
if (is_front_page()){ ?>
    RENDER HOMEPAGE FEATURE
<?php }
```

When I choose to switch language, the layout feature disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `lang` is a reserved/used query variable in WordPress, but if it's not, then adding might help. Use a filter on `query_vars` like this:

```
function my_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'lang';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );
```

Although WordPress will now know about the language query variable, I'm not sure what's causing your `is_front_page()` to stop returning true, perhaps it's not about your query variables but about the query itself, because `is_front_page()` depends on the `$wp_query` global object.

So how does your language plugin work? If you've set a page with an id of `10` as your front page, then `is_front_page()` for that page will return `true`, but if your language plugin is filtering the query and grabbing a page with an id of `50` (which is page 10 translated into Italian) then it's no longer the front page.

Give us a little bit more info about which plugin you're using to handle translations and if you wrote it yourself let us know how it works :)

Cheers!

Comment: I'm using qTranslate, and as far as I can tell, it just doubles the content of each page adding in <!-:en:--> and <!-:cy:--> to separate the languages, I don't think the pages double up as you suggested.

Comment: @Daniel you can easily check that, before calling `is_front_page` try to `print_r` the `$wp_query` global and see what changes between the two requests (the one with the lang query variable and the one without it).